# Using Stamen base layer offline in mobile application?

Tags: offline, mobile-gis, stamen

I am creating a mobile application using html/css/js and I am in the process of making it operational offline only.

I am using Stamen as a base layer so I want to use it offline too.

If this is possible, then how?

Comment: Are you doing this on a laptop or a phone/ laptop? If a laptop, then you could run a local tileserver. Does your application environment support vector tiles?

Comment: Mobile device only. Smartphone and tablet.

I am using OpenLayers 3 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got that working. My app is now fully working offline.

Turns out it is really easy to do it.

I used JTileDownloader (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JTileDownloader#Install) to download the tiles in {x}/{y}/{z}.png format. You need the tile server address to download the tiles from. So I found the Stamen tile server link here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers
There is a few tile servers to choose from, which is nice. I specified the zoom levels (ex: 8,9,10,11,12,13, ...) and the bounding box.

Now with OpenLayers 3 I just changed the layer definition:

```
layerBaseStamen = new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: 1,
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
        layer: 'watercolor'
    })
});
```

Is now

```
**layerBaseStamen = new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: 1,
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'maps/stamen/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});**
```

That's it. I now use Stamen tiles offline!

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think of is to pre cache the tiles as images or MBTiles for a predefined area of interest and load them on the  device before it is taken offline.

Comment: And how can I pre cache the tiles?

Comment: Thing more about you should check Stamen's terms and conditions to see if they allow offline caching.  Here is an OpenLayers offline cache exampie: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/offline-storage.html

Comment: The exemple you provided looks promising, but it is for OpenLayers 2. I can't seem to find CacheWrite and CacheRead in OpenLayers 3 API doc. Is this example valid for OL3 too ?